# Using SQL open query in R studio

Tags: sql, r, database

I have a connection established to a DB in my R studio via ODBC which has linked servers connected to it.
I need to implement an openquery to take data from SERVER1 inside R studio.

This is the SQL query i use in the DB:

```
select * from openquery(Server1, 'SELECT count(*)
                             FROM mydata 
                             GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, sys_created_on), 0)')
```

I integrated this as,

```
count <- dbGetQuery(mycon,'SELECT * from openquery(Server1, 'SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                        FROM mydata 
                                                        GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, sys_created_on), 0)')')
```

The above query isnt working as the symbol ' is creating a problem.
Ive tried '' and " as well.

How to I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried replacing first and last `'` by `"` ?

Comment: I did, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't working ?

```
count <- dbGetQuery(mycon, 'SELECT * openquery(Server1, \'SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                         FROM mydata 
                                                         GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, sys_created_on), 0)\')')
```

Comment: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mydata GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, sys_created_on), 0)'.

Comment: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 01000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionWrite (send()).

Comment: Not a syntax error this time. So it's seems to be good with this.

Comment: Thats great then :) let me clear up the rest and try it out again! Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Glad to helped you. Don't forget upvote and good answer mark for the other peoples.